# Did Obama tweet in any foreign languages during his presidency?

Tags: barack-obama, social-media

During Obama's presidency, did he tweet (or otherwise post on social media) in any foreign languages, akin to Trump's [tweet](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1216130169477439488) in Farsi today? (And yes, I'm aware that he probably didn't type out that tweet himself)

I'm aware of @LaCasaBlanca (which means "The White House" in Spanish), but that isn't part of either @BarackObama or @Potus44.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

President Obama tweeted "Chag Sameach" (Hebrew for Happy holiday) at Hanukkah and Passover, for example

> From our family to everyone celebrating Hanukkah, Chag Sameach. -bo [link](https://twitter.com/BarackObama/status/277509420760563712)

However the tweet was in English, with only a borrowed phrase, which was rendered in the Latin script. The "-bo" indicates that this was a personal tweet, and not written by a staffer. As far as I can tell from going through the twitter archive there was nothing comparable to a tweet entirely in Farsi.

While Obama knew some conversational Indonesian, he was only fluent in English, which he described as "embarrassing".